# when would you want to grant public read access to an s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm looking for use cases. The one I have in my mind is public read access if the media being stored in the bucket is user profile images or something like that. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why yes. Yes I am. If you want to use the url as a media url on your site for images or file views, downloads, you must use public-read yo.